# Editing odf - libreoffice/word documents in emacs

Tags: org-mode

Does emacs support editing odf.odt, that is open document format files? There are some `odf2org` convertors available like [python odt2org.py](https://bitbucket.org/josemaria.alkala/odt2org/wiki/Home). On running the command `python odt2org.py xyz.odf.odt`, it crashes like,

```
File "/home/sk/src/odt2org/odt2org.py", line 105, in <module>
    _list, _extra = _odtfile.gen_list()
  File "/home/sk/src/odt2org/odtfile.py", line 266, in gen_list
    _list = self.process_tables(_list)
  File "/home/sk/src/odt2org/odtfile.py", line 441, in process_tables
    _txt += _m['text'] + ' '
KeyError: 'text'
```

so, odf to org mode is the way to go (or) emacs has any plugins for directly loading `odt` type documents

Comment: [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) can also convert ODT to OrgMode.